# Write and read an ArrayList in 2 different Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist

I am currently working on a little project for school which is a TowerDefense game.

When initializing the game, it starts a Thread that calculates everything. After starting that Thread, my code jumps into a loop, that loops my graphics code. I think that it is using 2 Threads then. One thread is for calculating and the other one is the "standard" Thread, that is used when you open the program itself.

Now I wanted to add Projectiles to my Towers. For that I need to add a new Projectile Object to my Entity ArrayList. and whenever I try to do so it says

Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

and points to the line where my graphicsloop is, that tries to loop my Entity Array. That makes sense, because my graphicsloop tries to read while my Projectiles are added to this Array. I tried to work with "synchronized" and I think I know how to use it and what it is for, but Im not that sure where I would use it in my code. I try to solve this problem since yesterday and couldnt find anything on the Internet how to solve it. Also Im not sure what piece of Code helps you, if you didnt understand exactly how my program works and what the problem is so if you need anything, feel free to ask.

Would be awesome, if someone could help me solving this problem and I already want to thank you, if you are still reading

**edit:** I think these are the important pieces of code:

World update method:

```
private void updateRunning() {
    waveTimer();
    for (Entity e : entities) {
        if (e.isMonster() && !block) {
            e.toMonster().move();
            if (e.toMonster().getHealth() <= 0)
                entities.remove(e);
        } else if (e.isTower()) {
            e.toTower().setTarget(e.toTower().findTarget());
            e.toTower().shoot();
        } else if (e.isProjectile()) {
            e.toProjectile().update();
        }
    }
}
```

Renderer loop method:

```
private void updateRunning() {
    cam.update();
    for (Entity ent : world.getEntities()) {
        ent.draw();
    }
    cursor.update();
    cursor.draw(); // Must always be on bottom draw-methods, to be drawed
                   // on top of
                   // everything else
    cam.refresh();
}
```

**edit2**

```
private void addWave() {
  if (wave % 3 == 1) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      entities.add(new Monster(this, i + 1, path.getCoord(0).x,  
                   path.getCoord(0).y - i * 57, 0.35f, Assetloader.monster01));
    }
  } else if (wave % 3 == 2) {
  } else {
  }
}

private void attack(Monster target, float damage) {
  world.addEntity(new Projectile(world, vec.x, vec.y, 20, 20, target,  
                this, Assetloader.cursor01));
  ready = false;
  lastShot = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

public void addEntity(Entity e) {
  this.entities.add(e);
}
```

Comment: not to the point but helpful , read about THREAD LOCAL

Comment: It's hard to say what's going on without seeing some code. But what I think is going on, is that one thread tries to acces your list while an other thread is already iterating over that list. So, perhaps you'll have to use locks to give your threads concurrent access to the list. What you can try to use are list interfaces designed for this, such as CopyOnWriteArrayList or ConcurrentHashMap .

Comment: Show your game loop please. Usually `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` happens when you are removing stuff while iterating over it. That doesn't mean you are accessing things from different threads.

Comment: added both loops now and as you can see Im iterating simultaneously

Comment: @besplash see, nothing with threads. Just have a look at: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/05/avoid-concurrentmodificationexception.html or my answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you need to collect data in several threads, you should use a structure that supports concurrency. In Java, such classes can be found inside [`java.util.concurrent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package. For your case, you should use [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) class instead of `ArrayList`.

From my experience, using an `ArrayList` or a concurrent support variation of `ArrayList` is not the best option for these cases. It would be better using a concurrent queue like [`ConcurrentLinkedQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This one actually seems to work. My Projectiles arent flying at the moment, but that may be a different problem. Atleast my frames are fine and not missing any objects as sometimes before and I get no Exceptions. I let you know, if it solved my problem, when my Projectiles work with this solution

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of your problem, it seems that you are sharing a data structure between many threads.  The appropriate class for that is `java.util.Vector`, since it is (more or less) a synchronized version of an `ArrayList`

Comment: Since we have not seen the code, it may be just the appropriate situation.  Say they only need to add objects to the list, not checking it before nor doing anything more complicated.  Of course, in any other situation, Jon is right in that matter and they would need some synchronized block or something like that

Comment: I don't need to see the code to know that `Vector` is an option.

Comment: Tried to just replace my ArrayList with Vector, but it doesnt work so how exactly do I have to change my Code? I think it has something to do with your (more or less)

Comment: `Vector` won't prevent a `ConcurrentModificationException` when one thread inserts into the vector while another thread is iterating over it. That is exactly what the OP is experiencing.

Comment: @besplash If replacing it has not removed your problems, then maybe your situation is more complex as LuiggiMendoza and Kenster point in their comments.  Have a look at your code and think of the critical sections of it, and implement synchronized blocks to make sure that they get executed in mutual exclusion

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) from the concurrent collections' package to automatically synchronize access.

Beware, the internal `array` is copied every write as the name implies, so this can be challenging performance-wise.

Otherwise, you may want to go a bit more low-level and experiment with a [ReentrantReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you would want to use `synchronized` you would have to do something like that

```
synchronized(myList) {
    //Do stuff
}
```

So no other thread can access the list while another Thread is in the synchronized block.
But watch out for [deadlocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock)

Here you have a tutorial on `synchronized`
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/synchronized.html

Answer (score 0):

Just use the iterator feature to remove an item while iterating:

```
private void updateRunning() {
        waveTimer();
        Iterator<Entity> iterator = entities.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            Entity e = iterator.next();
            if (e.isMonster() && !block) {
                e.toMonster().move();
                if (e.toMonster().getHealth() <= 0)
                    iterator.remove(e);
            } else if (e.isTower()) {
                e.toTower().setTarget(e.toTower().findTarget());
                e.toTower().shoot();
            } else if (e.isProjectile()) {
                e.toProjectile().update();
            }
        }
    }
```

This has nothing to do with threads, you just can't remove elements from a list while iterating over it using the for-each loop.

Comment: Same Exception as before, but on the line "Entity e = iterator.next();"

Comment: @besplash can you please show the code where you are adding to the list?

Comment: Argh.. I cant show the code in a comment. Its just like entities.add(new Monster(arg01, arg02, arg03)); and that happens in the method waveTimer();

Comment: That formatting doesnt like me.. Took me 10 minutes to do that